# Change the dropdown of a google website using VBA

Tags: html, vba, webautomation

I'm using web elements via VBA. I'd like to be able to change the selection in a dropdown box on a google website:

[image: Default Drop down Box]

This is what happens to the webpage when you change the option:

[image]

I had a look at the html and when you make a selection this bit is changed:

[image: HTML]

Here's my code so far:

```
Set objCollection = IE.document.getelementsbyclassname(CLASSNAME)

objcollection(0).click
```

This brings up the menu box, but I don't know how then to change the selection?

I found that you can change the webpage via the `.FireEvent("OnChange")` method, but I'm still clueless how to change the value in the drop down.

I can change the text, but it doesn't change the selection (e.g. .value, .innerhtml)

Comment: Why don't you use the BigQuery APIs to call the import tool, and not mess with the interface?

Comment: That would be ideal, but the corporate firewall doesn't let us use dataflow and the API documentation is totally over my head

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to suggest without looking at the actual webpage, but still you can try something like this:

```
ie.Document.getElementById(":6m").Value = "Google Cloud Storage"

ie.Document.getElementById(":6m").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried using value, but it just changes the text and not the selection

Comment: Oh and it's Google Big Query, but possibly you need to sign up/pay in order to get a look at it